# Java Core or Java EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I know this question might be little silly but I can't seem to find the right answer. I studied Java in school and the java I know is object oriented and used Eclipse/Netbeans and also Notepad++ for coding. Used java API and i also know java swing library. When i went to interviews they asked me if i had any experience with Java spring, hibernate or Java EE since my resume implied that I am proficient with Java.

Can anyone tell me what is the name of the Java that I know?

Comment: I think its just "Core Java" + J2sE that you know.

Comment: So whats the difference between Core java and J2SE? J2SE is standard edition right?

Comment: @GGio There isn't any difference; J2SE is the old name for JSE, which is the base Java libraries (which includes a lot, including Swing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java SE; "Core Java".

It's not "J2SE" any more, hasn't been for years.

Neither Hibernate nor Spring are Java EE, but they're not part of Java itself, either. They're just wildly popular libraries/frameworks. Hibernate happens to be an implementation of JPA, and Spring supports some Java EE annotations. They can both be used in either Java SE or Java EE environments.

Comment: I think it doesn't make sense to say "Hibernate" as JSE when it is technically implementation of JPA specification which is part of JEE. I fee it is part of JEE.

Comment: @thinksteep It's *an* implementation of JPA, doesn't need to be used as such, and has no issues outside of JEE environments. It's simply incorrect to say it's "part of JEE" when it isn't, JEE has a very specific definition.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Core Java....Core java is all the basic classes and API's. It is the Java equivalent
of the "C lib" or the intrinsic controls and built-in-functions in VB.

These are then added to with extra API's to make a "platform", that is
the complete set of API's needed to run an application.

Core java + common API's exist for different application areas, so we
have the Java EE platform, the Java SE platform and the Java ME one, for example.

This is common sense, it means developers of paricular types of
applications need to add little or nothing to the platform to support
thier apps whilst avoiding ridiculous bloat.

Note that you can take "core java" and add to it all the packages you
need to make a full blown JSP web/app server. It is more convinient to
take a platform which allready has this type of stuff included.